# Repo "fatal: Invalid git file format: ...repo/repo/.git/clone.bundle"

Tags: android, git, repository

while I was doing repo sync, I got error "fatal: Invalid git file format: ...repo/repo/.git/clone.bundle"
It was in beginning but after that sync went smoothly with no errors.
Should I ignore this or do sync again after deleting the .repo folder (I mean, should I do it from beginning? actually, my limited speed pack got just finished, so doing repo sync again will be a pain....)
Also, I did repo sync again without deleting the .repo folder. It fetched every file successfully. So is it ok for me to proceed to building part?
Thanks.

Comment: Hello, this post is pretty old now (and Repo probably changed a lot in between) but did you find more information about this error? Thanks!